# Get the word/object dragged with cursor from a webpage using javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I was trying to create a simple addon for my firefox.
What I want is to get the word into a variable when I select & drag that word onto an icon on the menubar in firefox.

Is there anyway to get the url that word points to ?

For making it clear, if i drag a url into the space of open new tab in firefox , that url webpage opens up in a new tab. Similarly I want that url/word to be stored into a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read the MDC [Drag and Drop](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/Drag_and_Drop) documentation?

Comment: Being totally new to js, I was looking for some examples.
I got it anyway. Thanks

Comment: If MDC doesn't have enough examples, or you can't understand them, then they need to know so they can be improved!